# Why does the time complexity for my BST stays almost constant regardless of the number of input items

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I am trying to test the experimented time complexity of BST with the expected results to see the difference(if any).

I've tried different number of inputs by varying the loop for insertion but it seems like inserting, searching or deleting a number from this BST gives me the same run time.

```
import timeit

setup="""\

import random
import time
class Node(object):

        #Tree node: left and right child + data which can be any object

        def __init__(self, data):

            #Node Constructor
            #@param data node data object

            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.data = data

        def __repr__(self):
            return "Node With Data: %d" % self.data

        def insert(self, data):

            #Insert new node with data
            #@param data node data object to insert

            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            else:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)

        def lookup(self, data, parent=None):

            #Lookup node containing data
            #@param data node data object to look up
            #@param parent node's parent
            #@returns node and node's parent if found or None, None

            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    return None, None
                return self.left.lookup(data, self)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    return None, None
                return self.right.lookup(data, self)
            else:
                return self, parent

        def children_count(self):

            #Returns the number of children for a given node
            #@returns number of children: 0, 1, 2

            count = 0
            if self.left:
                count += 1
            if self.right:
                count += 1
            return count

        def descendant_count(self):

            #Counts all descendant nodes

            count = 0
            if self.left:
                count += 1 + self.left.descendant_count()
            if self.right:
                count += 1 + self.right.descendant_count()
            return count

        def delete(self, data):

            #Delete node containing data
            #@param data node's content to delete

            node, parent = self.lookup(data)
            if node:
                children_count = node.children_count()
                if children_count == 0:
                    # If node has no children then remove it
                    if parent.left is node:
                        parent.left = None
                    else:
                        parent.right = None
                    del node
                elif children_count == 1:
                    if node.left:
                        child = node.left
                    else:
                        child = node.right
                    if parent:
                        if parent.left is node:
                            parent.left = child
                        else:
                            parent.right = child
                    del node
                else:
                    parent = node
                    successor = node.right
                    while successor.left:
                        parent = successor
                        successor = successor.left
                    node.data = successor.data
                    if parent.left == successor:
                        parent.left = successor.right
                    else:
                        parent.right = successor.right
        def inorder_print(self):
            if self.left:
                self.left.print_tree()
            print (self.data)
            if self.right:
                self.right.print_tree()

        def print_each_level(self):
            # Start off with root node
            thislevel = [self]

            # While there is another level
            while thislevel:
                nextlevel = list()
                #Print all the nodes in the current level, and store the next level in a list
                for node in thislevel:
                    print (node.data)
                    if node.left: nextlevel.append(node.left)
                    if node.right: nextlevel.append(node.right)
                print
                thislevel = nextlevel

        def compare_trees(self, node):

            #Compare 2 trees
            #@param node tree's root node to compare to
            #@returns True if the tree passed is identical to this tree

            if node is None:
                return False
            if self.data != node.data:
                return False
            res = True
            if self.left is None:
                if node.left:
                    return False
            else:
                res = self.left.compare_trees(node.left)
            if self.right is None:
                if node.right:
                    return False
            else:
                res = self.right.compare_trees(node.right)
            return res

        def tree_data(self):

            stack = []
            node = self
            while stack or node:
                if node:

                    stack.append(node)
                    node = node.left
                else: # we are returning so we pop the node and we yield it
                    node = stack.pop()
                    yield node.data
                    node = node.right


root = Node(50000)
i=0
for i in range(0,100001):                     #number of inputs
    root.insert(random.randrange(1,100001,1)) #range of random inputs


"""

test    =   """\
#   code    to  be  tested
time.sleep(0.001)
#root.insert(100000)  #
root.lookup(10000)    # Testing either 1 of these 3
#root.delete(20)      #

"""
#   timer   object  creation
t   =   timeit.Timer(stmt=test, setup=setup)
#   running the test    100 times
print ("%.2f    ms/run" %   (1000   *   t.timeit(number =   100)    /   100))
```

Comment: So you're saying you get the same times more or less with 2 items versus 100,000?

Comment: Yes. I've even tried up to 2 million inputs. I took the code from https://github.com/laurentluce/python-algorithms/blob/master/algorithms/binary_tree.py

Comment: Your timing is probably dominated by the `time.sleep`. Why call that?

Comment: @AdamSmith I've got that from an appendix to test the run time and I honestly am not too sure myself either. The program wont run without 'time.sleep'. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to considerably increase the numbers of lookup / insertion / deletion to actually notice the difference. (keep in mind the difference will be in `log(n)` so it's very subtle by definition)

If you profile your testing code:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 <string>:2(<module>)
     22/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 bst.py:39(lookup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {time.sleep}
```

you see that the time it takes in the actual BST is extremely small and not noticeable. Let's increase the number of lookups / insertion / deletions under test:

with 100000 insertions in the setup, 10000 lookups under test

```
      ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
           1    0.003    0.003    0.109    0.109 <string>:2(<module>)
250000/10000    0.105    0.000    0.105    0.000 bst.py:39(lookup)
           1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
           1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
           1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {time.sleep}
```

With 10 insertions in the setup, 10000 lookups under test

```
     ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
          1    0.004    0.004    0.033    0.033 <string>:2(<module>)
50000/10000    0.027    0.000    0.027    0.000 bst.py:39(lookup)
          1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
          1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
          1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {time.sleep}
```

Comment: I understand that the amount of time will increase if i do more than 1 lookups/insert/delete but my goal is hopefully to be able to find the best case and worst case time complexity for BST. @ddr2

Comment: that does not change anything ;)

For worst case / best case, you will need to investigate which kind of inputs leads your BST into those states.

Comment: As an hint, you could try `root.insert(i)` in your setup, you will soon see how that impacts how long it takes.

Comment: Sorry. What i meant was that my goal is to find the time complexity for 1 search/delete/insert which I've tried up to 2 million inputs and the time remains approximately 1.2ms +/- . I've tried doing more search/insert/delete in my setup and yes, the time did increase but this is because the number of tasks increased. Am i right to say so?
Thank you so much for your replies. @ddr2

Comment: If you look more closely at the last 2 profiles, I only change the number of elements inserted during setup, not the number of operations during the test. To get timing for 1 operation inside the test, you could simply divide `tottime` by 10000. Keep in mind that there are worst / best case and having a random input to "setup" the test can considerably change the outcome.

Comment: Oh. I get what you mean now. I've started trying to work on the worst case first and i replaced the random numbers inserted to root.insert(i) so that i'll get a worst case (i.e. linked list alike) but encountered with a code problem of `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. As for my for loop, it works with 100 loops but when i increase to 1000 it shows that error. How can i rectify this problem? @ddr2

Comment: we're drifting away from the initial question so I am not gonna dive deeper here. That maximum recursion depth is just showing a "bug" in the Node code you're using ;) I will let you search recursion depth in Python and how to deal with it, SO has a ton of questions talking about it already.